# How to make auto size for textarea in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I found the following code to make the height of the textarea automatically when there is text, I have confusion when entering the code into the code I have
Below is the code I found

```
<textarea auto-resize style="resize: none;"></textarea>
```

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('sampleApp' , [])
    .directive('autoResize', autoResize);

    autoResize.$inject = ['$timeout'];

    function autoResize($timeout) {

        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function autoResizeLink(scope, element, attributes, controller) {

                element.css({ 'height': 'auto', 'overflow-y': 'hidden' });
                $timeout(function () {
                    element.css('height', element[0].scrollHeight + 'px');
                }, 100);

                element.on('input', function () {
                    element.css({ 'height': 'auto', 'overflow-y': 'hidden' });
                    element.css('height', element[0].scrollHeight + 'px');

                });
            }
        };

        return directive;
    };
})();
```

I'm at a loss to put it in my code here because I have the controller code already installed

```
<div class="auto cell">
  <div class="post-textarea">
    <textarea placeholder="Apa yang anda pikirkan?" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13" ng-model="postid"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```